# Getting Started with ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr3

a few days ago I posted this question on the ANTLR mailinglist, but didn't recieve any support. So I'm hoping you guys here can help me out:

I am currently trying to dig into Antlr as I find this tool very helpful. The last Time I used it, I generated something based upon a finished grammar.
This time I wanted to build my own grammar and really start understanding what's happening.

For this I decided to build a parser for some Wiki-Notation-Like text.

Here an example (without the -Start - and - End - row):

```
------------ Start ---------------
before
More before

And yet even more ...
[Lineup]
[Floor:Main Floor]
Test1
Test2
[Floor:Classics Floor]
Test3
Test4
Test5
Test6
[/Lineup]
after
more After
..

And even more.
------------ End ---------------
```

If the text contains a "Lineup" block, then this should be parsed. The content is at least one "Floor" followed by a number of Names, a new "Floor" or the closing "Lineup"
I managed my parser to parse the text if I change my grammar and the text I am trying to parse to "[Floor:]" (One Block) but I really need a name in there :(

As soon as I change my Grammar to support the Floor-Name, nothing works anymore.
Could you please help me with this? I'm not looking for someone that fixes it for me without a comment. I would really like to know why my grammar doesn't work.
I'm really stuck and I'm working on this for days now (Ok ... I admit, it's just my spare time after work ... but at least all of that).

Here comes my gammar. If I try to parse the full text, I allways get EarlyExitExceptions while parsing the  :( :

```
grammar CalendarEventsJava;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
* PARSER RULES
*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

event    : (
                               (LINE_CONTENT | NEWLINE)*
                               (lineup (LINE_CONTENT | NEWLINE)*)?
               );

lineup   : (LINEUP_OPEN NEWLINE floor+ LINEUP_CLOSE);

floor      : (FLOOR_OPEN LINE_CONTENT FLOOR_CLOSE NEWLINE lineupEntry+);

lineupEntry
                : (LINE_CONTENT? NEWLINE);

artist     : LINE_CONTENT;


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
* LEXER RULES
*------------------------------------------------------------------*/




LINEUP_OPEN
                :              '[Lineup]';
LINEUP_CLOSE
                :              '[/Lineup]';
FLOOR_OPEN
                :              '[Floor:';
FLOOR_CLOSE
                :              ']';

BLANKS               :              ( ' ' | '\t' )+;
NONBREAKING
                :              ~('\r' | '\n' | ']');
NEWLINE            :              '\r'? '\n';


// the content of a line consists of at least one non-breaking character.
LINE_CONTENT
                :              (NONBREAKING | ']')+ ;
```

I really hope you can help me, as I'm really anxious to really get started with ANTLR, cause I think it really rocks :)

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

If you examine the token stream after tokenizing your source, you'll see that the following tokens are fed to the parser:

```
LINEUP_OPEN  :: [Lineup]
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: [Floor:Main Floor]
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: Test1
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: Test2
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: [Floor:Classics Floor]
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: Test3
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: Test4
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: Test5
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINE_CONTENT :: Test6
NEWLINE      :: \n
LINEUP_CLOSE :: [/Lineup]
```

As you can see, there is never a `FLOOR_OPEN` created but `LINE_CONTENT` tokens instead.

Here's how you can manually debug your token stream:

```
String source = 
        "[Lineup]\n" +
        "[Floor:Main Floor]\n" +
        "Test1\n" +
        "Test2\n" +
        "[Floor:Classics Floor]\n" +
        "Test3\n" +
        "Test4\n" +
        "Test5\n" +
        "Test6\n" +
        "[/Lineup]";
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(source);
CalendarEventsJavaLexer lexer = new CalendarEventsJavaLexer(in);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
CalendarEventsJavaParser parser = new CalendarEventsJavaParser(tokens);
for(Object o : tokens.getTokens()) {
    CommonToken t = (CommonToken)o;
    System.out.println(parser.tokenNames[t.getType()] + " :: " + t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

### The solution

Changing:

```
FLOOR_OPEN
                :              '[Floor:';
```

to

```
FLOOR_OPEN   : '[Floor:' ~']'* ']';
```

(`FLOOR_CLOSE` can then be removed)

and changing:

```
NONBREAKING
            :              ~('\r' | '\n');
```

to:

```
NONBREAKING  : ~('\r' | '\n' | '[' | ']');
```

will result in the following parse tree:

[image]

### Comments

Note that the lexer rules `NONBREAKING` and `LINE_CONTENT` are very similar, you probably don't  want `NONBREAKING` to ever appear in the token stream. It's be better if you make `NONBREAKING` a fragment-rule. Fragment rules are only used by other lexer rules and will therefor never be used to create a "real" token:

```
fragment NONBREAKING  : ~('\r' | '\n' | '[' | ']');

LINE_CONTENT : NONBREAKING+;
```

Comment: Hey ... was a little confused as I just edited my question ;-)
I just hat a look at your changes and now it really does parse everything corretly ... thanks for that :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation. I applied your changes and it worked right away. Just a small question to the NONBREAKING excluding "[" and "]" as I bet my users will certainly use these chars in their descriptions, I tried without this and it worked too.

Comment: @chrisdutz, you are correct, that is because `FLOOR_OPEN   : '[Floor:' ~']'* ']';` does not make use of `NONBREAKING` anymore. So it's safe to keep `NONBREAKING` as you had it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
NONBREAKING
                :              ~('\r' | '\n');
```

is consuming the floor close. It will consume all characters up to the end of the line. Try excluding the floor close character from it.

Kate.